# How to accept message from user after bot's message?

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm trying to make telegram bot using talegram.bot library and i have a question about user messages: how can i make receiving message from user only after some text from bot? Here is [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHjNr.png) from BotFather

e.g. if user send message to bot-bot ignores the message text and responses like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkJVa.png), but if
user clicks on InlineKeyboardButton, bot sending to user message like "write your text", bot recieves that text and saves

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you use Telegram.dll library if you are a C# programmer and easily  Define a sample IF operation  like below code . you can control every thing if use the DLL file .

```
  String Token = "399684XXX:AAH_NiVFXXXXX";
  int ID=0;

  while (true)
        {
            bot.update = "true";
            ID = bot.chat_id;
            if (bot.message_text=="/contact-us"){
             bot.sendMessage.send(ID, "Email:name@website.com" + "\n" + "Website: www.website.com");
            }
            if (bot.message_text=="/apple")
            {
             bot.sendMessage.send(ID, "lap lap lap...");
            }
            else
            {
             bot.sendMessage.send(ID, "/contact-us" + "\n" + "/apple");
            }
        }
```